# looping over properties with similar name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of objects where most of the properties differ only by increasing number.

Name
Last_name
Week1
Week2
Week3
Week4
Week5
Week6
and so on.

I would like to be able to display their values in a table, but only for selected amount... let's say display only first 4 weeks.

as such, i would have to make and if statement for each of the weeks. I tried to loop over this object, but as far as I know, I can't increment the name of the property. Is there a way to loop over the object either where the name starts with a week%.... or increment the week number?

**My returned "final list of objects" that combines 2 lists.**

```
  List<WeekViewModel> results = new List<WeekViewModel>();
                results.AddRange(ReportData.Select(x =>
                      new WeekViewModel()
                      {

                          full_name = x.full_name,
                          location = x.location,
                          ...
                          week1 = Category.Where(c => c.Color_code == x.week1).FirstOrDefault(),
                          week2 = Category.Where(c => c.Color_code == x.week2).FirstOrDefault(),
                          week3 = Category.Where(c => c.Color_code == x.week3).FirstOrDefault(),

                      }));
```

each of the weeks is of a custom type Category with few props in them

```
 public class Category
    {

        public string Short_name { get; set; }
        public int Color_code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I basicly only need short name of each week. Not sure how to use C.Evenhuis suggestion here... Could someone please tell me how can i use reflection here ? I am not familiar with this concept

Comment: can you add your code here?

Comment: Look into reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I assume all `Week` properties in your `myObject` have the same data type, and for simplicity I've used `string` here:

You could have a `Dictionary<int, Func<string>>` that you populate beforehand:

```
Dictionary<int, Func<myObject, string>> weekMapping = new Dictionary<int, Func<myObject, string>>();
weekMapping[1] = (o) => o.Week1;
weekMapping[2] = (o) => o.Week2;
```

Then for ever `myObject` you have:

```
myObject o = ...;
for (int week = 1; week <= 2; week++)
{
    string weekValue = weekMapping[week](o);
}
```

You could also choose to use reflection, since you can then access properties by name, but it usually makes code more complex and less readable.

Comment: I have added my code to the question, not sure how to implement method mentioned by you in my case. Could you please give me some tip, on how to use reflection ?

Comment: There are tons and tons of examples out there on how to use reflection

Comment: <td>@(data.GetType().GetProperty("week" + i).GetValue(data, null))</td> this partialy works for me, but this returns whole, object and i need it to return .short_name of this object

Comment: `GetValue(...)` returns `object`, you'd need to cast it to the correct type so you can access its `short_name` property.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use reflection here in my view, and works great.

```
                @for (var i = 1; i < Model.numberOfWeeksx; i++)
                {
                    var xx = data.GetType().GetProperty("week" + i).GetValue(data, null);
                    var yy = xx.GetType().GetProperty("Short_name").GetValue(xx, null);
                    <td>@yy</td>

                }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you will have to extract the property names with reflection and find the matching property names and sort them yourself.
Make a method that finds public instance properties of a type with a name that matches a (regex)pattern.
Remember that if you do alphabetic sorting, Week10 will come before Week2.
Parse the number part as int and sort by that.